# Reading growing shared file: content apparently not updated, only meta

Tags: file, size, shared

So I happen to work on this project where a Linux server with a measurement card can run a process where the measured data is constantly added to a file. The directory is shared via SMB2 (samba) in a network. A Windows 7 PC have to read from the growing file at least every 0.5 seconds and get the latest samples from the data.

I need the filesize to get some samples there because the data is formatted in some sort of blocks with constant length, counting from the beginning.

It is a MATLAB project, but the following problem happen in Python as well (on the Windows machine!):

So I *open* the file, *seeking* to *end-of-file* and *tell* to get the filesize, reading data based on the filesize and afterwards *closing* the access. This is repeated every 0.5 seconds. However, as the data is written to the file, this filesize is constantly the value from the first access, and so I get always the same sample data.

Now, I can get the correct and up-to-date filesize using *dir* (MATLAB) or *os.stats* (Python), but when I seek near to that position and read, I get only empty data returned.

Note that I already discovered how to disable the caching of SMB in Windows using special registry entries which helped to get the current real filesize, but the size using tell is still not updated.

So I guess the filecontent itself is stored on the server until it stops writing to the file, but the filesize meta info seems to be transferred. When I run the Python script in the server, I get current samples without problems btw.

I know this is bad data exchange anyway, and it is already planned to change it (longterm). But for the short-run, how can I fix this?

Comment: Since you're already opening the file, what size does `GetFileSize()` return for the file?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628141/faster-way-to-get-file-size-information-c

Comment: I'v never done anything with C++... not sure how I can implement this snippets. But thanks, I may give it a try. Anyway, as the problem seems to be samba related, are there any parameters that could cause this behaviour? There are tons (testparm -v -s) and I already greped those with "cache" and looked at the man pages, but it is hard to tell wether they contribute to the problem or not.